# VSCode: move cursor to next occurrence of given word for each cursor

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have lines like:

```
"gg":: go to the top:: of the file
"G":: go to the bott::om of the file
"{":: go to the begi::nning of current paragraph
"}":: go to the end ::of current paragraph
"%":: go to the matc::hing pair of (), [], {}
"50%":: go to line a::t the 50% of the file
":NUM":: go to line ::NUM. :28 jumps to line 28
```

I have cursor in the beginning of each line. So, it looks like:

```
|"gg":: go to the top:: of the file
|"G":: go to the bott::om of the file
|"{":: go to the begi::nning of current paragraph
|"}":: go to the end ::of current paragraph
|"%":: go to the matc::hing pair of (), [], {}
|"50%":: go to line a::t the 50% of the file
|":NUM":: go to line ::NUM. :28 jumps to line 28
```

**NOTE:** Here I am using `|` as cursor.

Now, I want to move the cursor before first occurrence of `::` for each cursor,so that it looks like:

```
"gg"|:: go to the top:: of the file
"G"|:: go to the bott::om of the file
"{"|:: go to the begi::nning of current paragraph
"}"|:: go to the end ::of current paragraph
"%"|:: go to the matc::hing pair of (), [], {}
"50%"|:: go to line a::t the 50% of the file
":NUM"|:: go to line ::NUM. :28 jumps to line 28
```

I tried selecting text. then search in selection (`ctrl+f`>`alt+l`). then `alt+enter`. But the issues is, it selects all occurrence of `::` and not the first one.

what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by#move-by)

And define a key combo

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+f6",  // or any other key combo
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "moveby.regex",
    "args": {
      "ask": true,
      "properties": ["next", "start", "nowrap"]
    }
  }
```